# javaでクエリから取得した値を変数に格納できません。

Tags: java, sql

```
//クエリ
@NamedQuery(
            name = "id_select",
            query = "SELECT rf.id FROM ReportFavo AS rf WHERE rf.report_id = :report_id AND rf.employee = :employee"
            )

//クエリの値を変数へ格納
int id = em.createNamedQuery("id_select" , int.class)
                .setParameter("report_id" , report_id)
                .setParameter("employee" , employee_id)
                .getSingleResult();
```

エラーメッセージ

```
HTTPステータス 500 - Type specified for TypedQuery [int] is incompatible with query return type [class java.lang.Integer]
```

Answer (score 1):

JPAベースのフレームワーク(Hibernate等)をお使いでしたら、その旨本文かタグでお示しいただくと、そこら辺が詳しい方に見つけてもらいやすくなります。

エラーメッセージの

> ```
> Type specified for TypedQuery [int] is incompatible with query return type [class java.lang.Integer]
> ```

と言うのは、

> ```
> 型付きクエリーで指定された型(int)はクエリーの戻り値型(Integer)と非互換です
> ```

と言う意味ですから、まずはそこ(「型付きクエリーで指定された型」)を修正して見るべきでしょう。

```
int id = em.createNamedQuery("id_select" , Integer.class) //<- `Integer`を使う
                .setParameter("report_id" , report_id)
                .setParameter("employee" , employee_id)
                .getSingleResult();
```

Comment: ご教示いただきありがとうございます。修正できました。intとintegerを同義で考えてしまっていたようです。

Comment: @pko さん、ご報告ありがとうございます。最近のJavaコンパイラでは`int`と`Integer`を多くの場合自動変換してしまいますし、フレームワークの多くがどちらを指定しても大丈夫なように作られているんで、近年使い分けは以前より難しくなってきています。エラーメッセージの文は、自動翻訳などでは意味が掴みにくいかと思いますが、重要な情報が含まれているので、しっかり参考にしてください。

Comment: はい。ありがとうございます！